# 2 places for a sum, choose based on which one is not empty

Tags: excel, excel-2007, ms-office, excel-formula

I am creating a sheet for my taxes. I have columns such as equipment, leases,payroll, etc and another two columns which are 'bank out' and 'credit out'. So say I buy $100 worth of equipment and payed $200 for a lease and used my credit card for this transaction I want the 'credit out' to sum these up so it would display $300. But another time I might buy $50 worth of equipment but use my bank card out so now I would want my 'bank out' to sum to $50. I am using to show this example to show that my purchases are not always the same because sometimes I use credit or sometimes I use my bank account. My idea is when I am entering in my information to type I type in anything into either bank out or credit out and then have an if statement which checks if the cell is empty and if it is leave it blank, but whichever one of them is not empty to have the sum. So either bank out or credit out will always have a value and one will not. I have tried many different statements such as

```
if(a2="","",sum(c2:s2))
```

where a2 is the credit out and c2-s2 are all the sums of my purchases but I get a circular reference warning and the same happens for my bank out when I type in a similar equation). The purpose of this is sometimes in one row I might make a purchase using 10 or more different categories and I just want the total to be correct and avoid human mistake.

Comment: How will the formula know whether a transaction is a `credit out` or a `bank out`? Do you have something to indicate this in your excel sheet?

Comment: My idea was somehow to put something inside the credit out for instance the letter 'c" or anything. Excel then would check to see if the column is blank and if it is leave it blank, but if it not (the letter r 'c' is in it so it is not blank) it would calculate the sum in the cell which is not blank. This does not seem to work though because I get an error that this is a circular reference. I am open to any idea.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot (upload it to an online image host and post the link) or create a sample table as example in your question? As it is right now, it seems you can just use one column for the total amount and a second column to indicate whether it's `credit` or `bank`.

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone right now. This is what I have been doing (having an extra column in which I would type bank or credit and then everything works). I would like to though remove this column if possible and have a better alternative way of completing this task.

Comment: You cannot have a formula checking the cell in which it is itself found in. What about keeping two rows, one for credit and one for bank, for the same... (I don't know what each row contains...) day perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't what you asked for, the easiest solution to achieve what you're looking to do would be to insert in a new column called "Transaction Type".

Then, if `Transaction Type` = "Bank", have the bank column populate and if `Transaction Type` = "Credit" have the Credit column populate.

This can then easily be accomplished by both columns referencing that other cell and it's just a simple "If" statement from that point forth... Your way has the problem that each cell is referencing another cell that references back to itself, therefore causing a circular reference.

Hope this makes sense / does the trick for you....

Comment: Yes this is what I have been doing and it seems to be the only solution. Thank you for everyone's input!